# Plot CPU usage over time

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I have a csv file with cpu usage overtime (which tracks the top 10 PID over time)
The csv structure is bellow (time - millis since epoch, pid, and cpu usage value)

```
+-------+------+------+
| Time  | PID  | CPU% |
+-------+------+------+
| time1 | pid1 |   10 |
| time1 | pid2 |   20 |
| time2 | pid1 |   50 |
| time2 | pid2 |   10 |
+-------+------+------+
```

My goal is to create a graph which will look something like this:
[image: expected graph]

I've tried Google Spreadsheet & Excel to achieve something like this, but I can't figure out how to 'group' by a column (in my case PID) and how to use CPU values on the PID over time

I would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You can create a Excel pivot table and then chart of it? Like Time in Rows, PIDs in Columns and CPU% in Values ... Data in the text and the chart dont match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pivot your data the following way:

`=QUERY(A1:C, "SELECT A, SUM(C) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A PIVOT B",1)`

- Select the data created in previous step and insert a `Line chart`.

Result would be something like this:

[image]